# java: incompatiable types. Required: boolean, found java.lang.String error msg

Tags: java

I have an array configured with students names, IDs, and grades, etc.  I'm writing a method to pull the grades from the array, but I get this "boolean error" because I have a string. How do I correct it?

Here is the piece of code in question:

```
//code to print the students GPA based off the three grades received in  class
public static void print_average_grade(String myStudentID)
{
    for (Student variable : myStudent)
    {
        if (variable.getId() = (myStudentID)) //if statement is kicking back error....
        {
            double gpa = ((variable.getMyGradeA() + variable.getMyGradeB() + variable.getMyGradeC()) / 3);
            System.out.println("Student with ID# " + myStudentID + " has a GPA of " + gpa);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`=` denotes assignment. For comparison, use `==` (compare by reference) or `.equals()` (compare by value).

I.e., `variable.getId() = (myStudentID)` should probably be `variable.getId().equals(myStudentID)`

Answer (score -1):

`=` is an assignment operator, which means it assigns the RHS to the LHS

```
foo=bar;   //the variable foo now contains the value bar
```

To check for equality use `==`

```
foo==bar; //returns true or false
```

However, with reference variable, `==` only checks if they refer to the same object, so for comparison of two `Strings` you should use

```
variable.getId.equals(myStudentId);  //checks if the values of the Strings is the same
```